# Finding Xpath which matches multiple texts

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am looking for xpath for "Medicaid ID" text as shown below. When I use `"//*[@id='details']/form/p[4]/label"` xpath, I am getting text "Medicaid Id: 1234567". I dont want 2nd text after space(1234567). I just want "Medicaid Id" Text XPATH only. Please help me.

```
<p>
<label>
Medicaid Id:
<span class="indented">1234567 </span>
</label>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">   attrCnt++; </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the text is split with a span (which contains the numbers) you should be able to access the text before the span with:

```
//*[@id='details']/form/p[4]/label/text()[1]
```